# Jenkins does not start Xvnc

Tags: jenkins, plugins, vnc

Here is the snippet of my Jenkinsfile:

```
stage ('Eggplant') {
      steps {
             wrap([$class: 'Xvnc']) {
                        //run my eggplant test here
            }
     }
}
```

On the build console, i used to see this output:

```
Starting xvnc
[my_pipeline] $ vncserver :94 -localhost -nolisten tcp
```

However, since last week, I don't see that output anymore and my eggplant test does not get executed anymore.  I have not changed anything.  Does anyone know what cause Xvnc to stop working?  Do I need to reinstall Xvnc plugin?

Comment: It worked last week, but not this week? What did you change? Nothing? Well, maybe something small, but that should not affect anything". Patches,, updates?

Comment: As far as I remember, there is nothing change.   Is there anything I can look for to troubleshoot this?

Comment: found the issue and the solution: the log file indicated that all display numbers are allocated.  So, I had to remove the display numbers from the <allocatedNumber> section of the /var/lib/jenkins/hudson.plugins.xvnc.Xvnc.xml

Comment: That's good. I just have decades of experience to never believe anyone when they say "I changed NOTHING!". They are usually slightly less culpable than those who said "I only made a small change, but that should not affect anything".